# ArrayList as a paramater in constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I am struggling to comprehend the ArrayList when used in a constructor.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class Names {
    ArrayList<String> names;
    private int number;
    
    public Names(int numberIn, ArrayList<String> namesIn) {
        number = numberIn;
        names = namesIn;
    }
}
```

If I created another class to test the names class like so:

```
public class NamesTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Names n = new Names(10, ??? );
    }
}
```

How can I add to the array using the constructor's parameter? Do I list the names somehow where the question marks are?

I can't figure this out so any help would be much appreciated.
Just to clarify, when creating a new object 'n' in the NamesTester class, I would like to call the constructor so that the number of students (10) and their names ("Jack", "John", etc.) are held in the 'names' and 'number' attributes so that when I add the setters for both, I can print them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question more ?

Comment: You need to pass an array list. `new Names( 10, new ArrayList<>());` Or you could use `Arrays.asList( "one", "two", "three")` but that isn't an array list, just a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just do :

```
public class NamesTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("bob");
        names.add("sally");
        //you can add more here till you get 10 names....
        Names n = new Names(10, names );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I ended up doing and worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correct, you need to pass in a new ArrayList to the Names constructor class, and maybe add a method to add elements to that list, so e.g.

```
public class Names {

    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private int number;
    
    public Names(int numberIn, ArrayList<String> namesIn) {
        number = numberIn;
        names = namesIn;
    }

    public void addName(String name) {
        if (names != null) {
            names.add(name);
        }
    }
}

public class NamesTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Names n = new Names(10, new ArrayList<>());
        n.addName("alice");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at each step separately.

`ArrayList<T>` is an ordinary Reference Type (i.e. Class), like any other class, be it a `String`, `Integer`, `Date`, or `YourCustomClass`. The only difference is that it is a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

When you define method parameter (for example `ArrayList<T> list`), you define it with:

1. Parameter Type (which is `ArrayList<T>` from above example);
2. Variable identifier (variable name, which is `list` from the same example);

Now, have a look at your code again:

```java
public class Names {
    ArrayList<String> names;
    private int number;
    
    public Names(int numberIn, ArrayList<String> namesIn) {
        number = numberIn;
        names = namesIn;
    }
}
```

Your constructor (which is, by definition, a special kind of method) expects two arguments: first of type `int`, and second of type `ArrayList<String>`.

I assume you know how to create object, with `new` keyword.

So, you can either create an object and pass its reference to the constructor, like:

```java
ArrayList<String> myObj = new ArrayList<>();
Names names = new Names(10, myObj);
```

or instantiate your object inline, right when you call the constructor, like:

```
Names names = new Names(10, new ArrayList<String>());
```

Finally, what you want to do is to add the objects into your `ArrayList<String>` instance, and it is done like:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Jack");
list.add("John");
//and so on.
```

Comment: Good breakdown of the problem and an excellent explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably want everything declared a `java.util.List` rather than `ArrayList`.  In the vast majority of usecases, specifying the concrete collection type is undesireable as it forces you to use only a specific implementation, and just leads to lots of headaches.

The easiest way to specify and construct a list in java is using the one of the [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--) methods.  Note that these lists are immutable, and cannot be changed (e.g. added to or removed from).

This would look something like:

```
public class Names {
    List<String> names;
    private int number;

    public Names(int numberIn, List<String> namesIn) {
        number = numberIn;
        names = namesIn;
    }
}

public class NamesTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Names n = new Names(10, List.of("Joe", "Jill", "Bob", "Bobilina" );
    }
}
```